# Open web video with nodejs

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, stream, vlc, omxplayer

Hi i'm trying to build a nodejs app on my raspberry pi model 4 that after receiving an input (nfc tag)
open a url that contain a video.

**Es 'http://www.example.com/webapi/content?rfid=05:66:77:66:93:67'.**

The problem is that when i try to open my link with vlc or omxplayer it drop an error and doesn't show me any video. I try to put the link in the "open network stream" on vlc in windows and i have the same issue, but if i put the link in the browser I see the video correctly. If i try to open other videos i didn't get any problem.

Unfortunately I can't post the link to the site for privacy reasons. Any advice on what the problem might be?

Error log on raspberry pi:

```
[01cf9b80] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[01d089f0] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[01d089f0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[01c72b58] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[01d152c0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[01c72b58] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[01c72b58] main libvlc: Esecuzione di vlc con l'interfaccia predefinita. Usa 'cvlc' per utilizzare vlc senza interfaccia.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
[01d152c0] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[01d152c0] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> [b1002098] mp4 stream error: no moov before mdat and the stream is not seekable
[b1001e58] prefetch stream error: cannot seek (to offset 48)
[b1054990] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xb104e340] stream 0, offset 0x4d3: partial file
```

Comment: what's the error you get ?

Comment: i edit with the log

Comment: What is the content type returned from that link?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis it's video/mp4